# How to let a script know the code of a file that imports that script?

Tags: python, import

I'm trying to create a script in python that print things based on the code of the program that imports this script.
I have an analyzer called `analyzer.py` and I want that when a program imports analyzer it passes (without explicitly writing it) the code itself to the analyzer.

For example if `some_code.py` is something like:

```
import analyzer
x = 5
x += 1
print(x)
```

`analyzer.py` should work like:

```
if "print" in code
    """
    inside code I have:

    import analyzer
    x = 5
    x += 1
    print(x)
    """
    #...
```

Is there a way to do something like this?

Comment: Why not do this as a script that takes the file to analyze as a parameter?

Comment: I would like the user to simply import analyzer without calling it directly by passing it parameters, in order to make the analysis automatic when anlyzer is imported

Comment: I don't undertand the problem, but it's seems that you can read as plain text file:
`with open('some_code.py') as fil:
    content = fil.read()`

Comment: AFAIK there is no way for the `analyzer.py` module to access or determine what script is currently importing it.

Comment: Thanks to everybody